# SQL Server 2014 - Sum Working Hour group by Day/Night Time, Week/Weekend, Regular/Overtime

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a list of tasks,
for each I have a TaskID, startTime and StopTime as milliseconds from 1-1-1970 and a list of users (#Tasks).

I need to calculate the time spent by each user on the task splitted by day/night time, week or weekend, regular/overtime considering nighttime hours from 10:00 PM to 06:00 AM.

Surely there's a better solution but so far I got this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Tasks') IS NULL
    BEGIN
        create table #Tasks
        (
            TaskID nvarchar(50), 
            DateStart bigint, 
            DateStop bigint,
            Staff nvarchar(100)
        )

        insert into #Tasks values
        ('C001',1554181200000,1554190200000,'john,jack'),
        ('C002',1554202800000,1554212700000,'tom,john'),
        ('C003',1554228000000,1554246900000,'john,franck'),
        ('C004',1554613200000,1554626700000,'john')
    END
GO

declare
  @UserName     nvarchar(50)='john',
  @DateFrom     datetime='2019-04-01', 
  @DateTo       datetime='2019-04-30',
  @nStart       time='06:00:00',
  @nStop        time='22:00:00'

  select
    startday as [Day],
    sum([WeekDay]) as [WeekDay],
    sum([WeekNight]) as [WeekNight],
    sum([WeekendDay]) as [WeekendDay],
    sum([WeekendNight]) as [WeekendNight],
    sum([TotalMinutes]) as [TotalMinutes],
    0 WeekDayOverTime, 
    0 WeekNightOvertime, 
    0 WeekendDayOvertime, 
    0 WeekendNightOvertime,
    [UserName]
    ,timeframe
  from
  (
      select
        iif(isWeekend=1,NightMinutes,0) WeekendNight,
        iif(isWeekend=0,NightMinutes,0) WeekNight,
        iif(isWeekend=1,DayMinutes,0) WeekendDay,
        iif(isWeekend=0,DayMinutes,0) [WeekDay],
        TotalMinutes,
        username,
        startday,
        timeframe
       from 
       (
          select
            iif(Before6>0,Before6,0)+ iif(After22>0,After22,0) NightMinutes,
            TotalMinutes-iif(Before6>0,Before6,0)- iif(After22>0,After22,0) DayMinutes,
            TotalMinutes,
            startday,
            isWeekend,
            UserName,
            timeframe
            from 
            (
                Select 
                    (t.datestop-t.datestart)/60000 TotalMinutes,
                    datediff(n,convert(time,DATEADD(SECOND,t.DateStart/1000,'1970-01-01')),@nStart) Before6,
                    datediff(n,@nStop,convert(time,DATEADD(SECOND,t.DateStop/1000,'1970-01-01')))   After22,
                    iif((((DATEPART(DW, convert(datetime,DATEADD(SECOND,t.DateStart/1000,'1970-01-01'))) - 1 ) + @@DATEFIRST ) % 7) IN (0,6),1,0) isWeekend,
                    convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(SECOND,t.DateStart/1000,'1970-01-01'),126) startday,
                    STUFF(( SELECT distinct ' ' + convert(varchar(5),DATEADD(SECOND,t.DateStart/1000,'1970-01-01'),108)+'-'+convert(varchar(5),DATEADD(SECOND,t.DateStop/1000,'1970-01-01'),108) AS [text()]
                        FROM #Tasks tt
                        --WHERE tt.taskID=t.TaskID               
                        FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 1, '' ) AS [timeframe],
                    @UserName UserName
                FROM #Tasks t
                WHERE t.Staff like '%'+@UserName+'%'
                and DATEADD(SECOND,t.DateStart/1000,'1970-01-01') between @DateFrom and @DateTo
            ) z
        ) zz
    ) zzz
    group by startday,username,timeframe
    order by startday
```

I need now to :
    1) group result by day, summing up WeekDay,WeekNight,WeekendDay,WeekendNight and TotalMinutes, and concatenating timeframe so to have for example on 2nd April  "05:00-07:30|11:00-13:45|18:00-23:00"
    2) Not sum up time between 12:00 and 12:30 (if applicable) since it is lunch time
    3) considering that after 8 hours daily it has to be calculated as overtime, I have to split the total minutes between in time and overtime, but depending if overtime is by daytime or nighttime or on the weekend
    4) eventually using a holiday table

in other words we should have this:

```
    Day         TotalMinutes    WeekDay WeekNight   WeekendDay  WeekendNight    WeekDayOverTime WeekNightOvertime   WeekendDayOvertime  WeekendNightOvertime    UserName    timeframe
    02/04/2019  630               420     60            0            0                 45                75                   0                    0              john      05:00-07:30|11:00-13:45|18:00-23:00
    07/04/2019  225                0       0          165           60                  0                 0                   0                    0              john      05:00-08:45
```

because (on 2nd April) we have:
First Task:
60 minutes of Regular NightTime
90 minutes of Regular DayTime

Second Task:
165 minutes of Regular DayTime, but have to count only 135 due to lunch time

Third Task:
240 DayTime
 75 NightTime
but since with Task 1 and 2 we sum up 285 minutes, only the first 185 Minutes of Third task are Regular DayTime: the remaining 45 are Overtime DayTime, and the following 75 of NightTime are actually OvertimeNightTime

Comment: "startTime and StopTime as milliseconds from 1-1-1970" Why not simply `datetime2`?

Comment: 'cause we use jquery fullcalendar that uses such format and having such commitment we found convenient to use it as standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this approach the first CTE (properDates) get the Start and Stop Datetimes, then you don't need to repeat that formula over the query.

The second CTE(splittedMinutes) is to get the same data you get in your current approach, except for the first CROSS APPLY, which is splitting the timeframes crossing with lunch time. The second CROSS APPLY gets the number of minutes and isWeekend value.

In the third CTE(qualifiedMinutes) I am using a window partition to get the accumulated minutes and generate the overtimes when applies.

At the end I used a selective SUM to separate weekdays and weekends in the aggregates

```
;with properDates AS (
    SELECT TaskID, DATEADD(SECOND,t.DateStart/1000,'1970-01-01') as DateStart,DATEADD(SECOND,t.DateStop/1000,'1970-01-01') as DateStop, Staff
    FROM #Tasks t
    WHERE Staff LIKE '%' + @UserName + '%'
), splittedMinutes AS (
select
    CAST(p.DateStart AS DATE) as [Day],
    TotalMinutes,
    SUM(TotalMinutes) OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(p.DateStart AS DATE) ORDER BY b.start) AS cumulate,
    TotalMinutes - EarlyMinutes - LateMinutes  as DayTime,
    EarlyMinutes + LateMinutes as NightTime,
    isWeekend,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),b.Start,108) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),b.Stop,108) as [timeframe]
    from properdates p
    cross apply (
        select CAST(p.DateStart As TIME) AS Start, @bStart as Stop WHERE CAST(p.DateStart AS TIME) < @bStart and CAST(p.DateStop AS TIME) > @bStart
        union 
        select @bStop as Start, CAST(DateStop AS TIME) AS Stop WHERE CAST(p.DateStop AS TIME) > @bStop and CAST(p.DateStart AS TIME) < @bStop
        union 
        select CAST(p.DateStart AS TIME) AS Start, CAST(p.DateStop AS TIME) AS Stop WHERE NOT (CAST(p.DateStart AS TIME) < @bStart and CAST(p.DateStop AS TIME) > @bStart) AND NOT (CAST(p.DateStop AS TIME) > @bStop and CAST(p.DateStart AS TIME) < @bStop)
    ) b
    cross apply (
        select 
        DATEDIFF(Minute, b.Start, b.Stop) as TotalMinutes,
        (DATEDIFF(Minute, CAST(b.Start AS TIME), @nStart) + ABS(DATEDIFF(Minute, CAST(b.Start AS TIME), @nStart))) / 2 as EarlyMinutes,
        (DATEDIFF(Minute, @nStop, CAST(b.Stop AS TIME)) + ABS(DATEDIFF(Minute, @nStop, CAST(b.Stop AS TIME)))) / 2 as LateMinutes,
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(DW, p.DateStart) IN (1,7) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isWeekend 
    ) c
), qualifiedMinutes As (
    SELECT Day, TotalMinutes, RegularDay, RegularNight, OvertimeDay, OvertimeNight, isWeekend, timeframe
    FROM splittedMinutes
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT RegularDay = CASE WHEN cumulate <= @maxTime THEN DayTime WHEN DayTime - (cumulate - TotalMinutes - @maxTime) > 0 THEN ABS(cumulate - TotalMinutes - @maxTime) ELSE 0 END
    ) RD
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT OvertimeDay = DayTime - RegularDay
    ) OWD
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT RegularNight = CASE WHEN cumulate <= @maxTime THEN NightTime WHEN (cumulate - TotalMinutes - @maxTime + RegularDay) < 0 THEN NightTime + (cumulate - TotalMinutes - @maxTime + RegularDay) ELSE 0 END
    ) RWN
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT OvertimeNight = NightTime - RegularNight
    ) OWN
)

SELECT 
    Day,
    @UserName and UserName, 
    SUM(TotalMinutes) AS TotalMinutes,
    SUM(CASE WHEN isWeekend = 0 THEN RegularDay ELSE 0 END) AS WeekDay,
    SUM(CASE WHEN isWeekend = 0 THEN RegularNight ELSE 0 END) AS WeekNight,
    SUM(CASE WHEN isWeekend = 1 THEN RegularDay ELSE 0 END) AS WeekendDay,
    SUM(CASE WHEN isWeekend = 1 THEN RegularNight ELSE 0 END) AS WeekendNight,
    SUM(CASE WHEN isWeekend = 0 THEN OvertimeDay ELSE 0 END) AS WeekDayOverTime,
    SUM(CASE WHEN isWeekend = 0 THEN OvertimeNight ELSE 0 END) AS WeekNightOvertime,
    SUM(CASE WHEN isWeekend = 1 THEN OvertimeDay ELSE 0 END) AS WeekendDayOverTime,
    SUM(CASE WHEN isWeekend = 1 THEN OvertimeNight ELSE 0 END) AS WeekendNightOvertime,
    STUFF((SELECT '|' + timeframe FROM qualifiedMinutes tt WHERE tt.Day = q.Day ORDER BY timeframe FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 1, '' ) AS [timeframe]
FROM qualifiedMinutes q
GROUP BY Day
```

Comment: Wow!, far beyond my knowledge and expectations..
thanks alot.
I'll try now to integrate an holidayTable